# How to sanitize a string removing specific character?

Tags: c#

I have this string:

```
PO Box 162, Ferny Hills
QLD 4055
Brisbane
```

which contains these character:

[image]

I want remove this charactes, so I tried:

```
info.Address = dd[i].InnerText
                    .Replace("\n", " ")
                    .Replace(" ", "")
                    .Replace(",", ", ");
```

but didn't works, I get all the character of the string attached. I'm expecting this result: `PO Box 162, Ferny Hills QLD 4055 Brisbane`.

Comment: So you want to replace new lines in your string?

Comment: Try `.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ", ")`

Comment: the new lines, and the space too long

Comment: What is the exact output you get from your code? It should replace the newlines fine.

Comment: @DavidG I get: POBox162,FernyHillsQLD4055Brisbane

Comment: In that case, see the duplicate.

Comment: Try using `.Replace("  ", " ")` where the first string is 2 spaces and the second is 1.

Comment: @itsme86 That won't work for 3 or more spaces.

Comment: If s is the text, use Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s, "[ ]{2,}", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline), "\r|\n", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(original.Replace(",", ", "), @"\s{2,}", " ").Replace(" ,", ",");`

Comment: @DavidG You're right.

Comment: @user1515791 do not copy/paste answers from other questions; instead, flag this question as duplicate.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann, the MultiLine part here is usefull i hope... I did not see it in the other question. (and i did not copy anything)

Comment: @DavidG: I'm sorry for adding the disturbance.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It's OK man, hopefully we're both just looking for the same thing here - good quality content for everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you replaced all blanks by nothing ( `.Replace(" ", "")` ). What did you expect? Now all your blanks are gone.

If you don't want that, don't do it.

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the space because is too long

Comment: You could try to `Split` your string, then trim each line and then concatenate them.

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this, by splitting and trimming the string to remove spaces and join them back by newline

```
var address = dd[i].InnerText.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine })
                    .Select(s => s.Trim());    
info.Address = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, address);
```

Comment: You're assuming the source text is using `Environment.NewLine` and doesn't come from another source that could be anything.

Comment: @DavidG, hmm thought so

Comment: I mean, it's probably fine, but I think the dupe covers the answers more comprehensively.